# Retrieve fingerprints from sql server data VarBinary(Max) in winForm pictureBox

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am using secugen fingerprint reader and sdk ...with sdk i am able to scan fingerprint,match,verify and display fingerprint image in pictureBox on runtime.. but not able to save in database.. i trien my on code to save fingerprints in database.. 
this is insertion code

```
 private void BtnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 iError;
            bool matched1 = false;
            bool matched2 = false;
            SGFPMSecurityLevel secu_level;

            secu_level = (SGFPMSecurityLevel)comboBoxSecuLevel_V.SelectedIndex;

            iError = m_FPM.MatchTemplate(m_RegMin1, m_VrfMin, secu_level, ref matched1);
            iError = m_FPM.MatchTemplate(m_RegMin2, m_VrfMin, secu_level, ref matched2);

            if (iError == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
            {
                if (matched1 & matched2)
                {
                    StatusBar.Text = "Verification Success";
                    //string name = "sumi";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HP; user=sa; password=Admin1; Initial Catalog=schoolmanagement; Integrated Security=True");
                    string qry = "INSERT into teacher_fingerprint (teacher_id,name,teacher_fingerprints)values (@teacher_id,@name,@teacher_fingerprints)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                    pictureBoxV1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacher_id", comboBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text + " " + textBox3.Text);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacher_fingerprints", m_VrfMin);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacher_fingerprints",pic);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusBar.Text = "Verification Failed";
                }
            }
            else
                DisplayError("MatchTemplate()", iError);
        }
```

and this my DrawImage function

```
 private void DrawImageImg(Byte[] imgData, PictureBox picBox)
        {
            int colorval;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(m_ImageWidth, m_ImageHeight);
            picBox.Image = (Image)bmp;

            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
                {
                    colorval = (int)imgData[(j * m_ImageWidth) + i];
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(colorval, colorval, colorval));
                }
            }
            picBox.Refresh();
        }
```

this my database .. i dont know this fingerprint binary is valid or not?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLXVz.png)

i tried to select fingerprint data in pictureBox but its not working 
it gives out of index error in drawImage function 
this is my selection code

```
     m_RegMin5 = new Byte[400];

if (iError == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
                    {
                      DrawImage(fp_image, pictureBox1);
                      StatusBar.Text = "Device Message: Finger On";

                      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP; user=sa; password=Admin1; Initial Catalog=schoolmanagement; Integrated Security=True");
                      string query = "select teacher_fingerprints from teacher_fingerprint where teacher_id=2 ";
                      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                      conn.Open();
                      m_RegMin5 = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
                      DrawImageImg(m_RegMin5,pictureBox2);
                    }                      
                    else
                     {
                      DisplayError("GetImage()", iError);
                        }
```

Comment: My guess you want to adjust your for loops in your function to Width - 1 and Height - 1. I would also caution you about AddWithValue, it doesn't always guess the correct datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ And I would also urge you to look into creating a layered application instead of sticking your sql directly in your code. It becomes a lot more hassle for maintenance in the long run the way you have this.

Comment: please provide some demo code. i didn't understand

Comment: Try changing bmp.Width to bmp.Width - 1. And do the same with Height. This is purely a guess because I can't see your data and not really sure what is happening. You need to set some break points in your code and debug it.

Comment: its not working

Comment: So add some breakpoints in your code and debug it. I can't step through this for you. But when dealing a person remotely saying "its not working" does not provide any information. You need to explain the situation.

Comment: index out of range error in drawImage function on 2nd last line

Comment: getting same error as described above

Comment: So add some breakpoints in your code and debug it. I can't debug this for you. It is painfully obvious that you are trying to reference a pixel in the image that doesn't exist. You have to analyze your code during run time and figure out the issue.